# How to add a Python Language Version to an environment?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, python-3.6

I was able to make a new Python environment for version 3.6, with similar settings as 3.5, except for the version number. The only problem is that I can't find an option to add Python language version 3.6 to the dropdown.

[image]

The Windows command prompt correctly displays "Python 3.6.0" on `python --version`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the language version, I just chose 3.5 and gave it the environment variable name(for me it was **Path**) for Python 3.6. It worked like a charm.

If you have not added Python to the Windows system environment variable, I suggest you do so.